# foreach error: cannot operate on type because it does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I am getting an error related to foreach which states:

> Foreach statement cannot operate on type ' ' because it does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

I am not getting what to do with this error. Please suggest the changes to be made to improve and correct the error in the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     store store = new store();
    public List<item> insert= new List<item>();//this is the list of second list items


    BindingSource itemslist = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource selectitem2 = new BindingSource();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setupdata();
        itemslist.DataSource = store.items;
        item.DataSource = itemslist;//linked between the two
        // what to print inside
        item.DisplayMember = "Display";
        item.ValueMember = "Display";
        //put the data to the selected item list
        selectitem2.DataSource=insert;
        selected_item.DataSource = selectitem2;

        selected_item.DisplayMember = "Display";
        selected_item.ValueMember = "Display";

    }


    private void purchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (item item in selected_item)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: keshava please code only where you getting the error and attach screenshot of the error...

Comment: Please provide a compilable [mcve]. Your question, as it stands, is neither compilable, nor an MCVE.

Comment: what type is `selected_item` ? a `ComboBox` ? `ListBox` ? ect ?? but nevertheless you cannot iterate through a control. It has no enumerator as the error message tells you you need to iterate through the underlying data collection. in your case it would be `insert`

Comment: @MongZhu selected_item is ListBox

Comment: Why is a listbox called `selected_item`? Presumably you want to iterate through `selected_item.Items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot iterate through a control (`ListBox`). 
It has no enumerator as the error message tells you. You need to iterate through the underlying data collection.

In your case it would be `insert`

so change the loop line into this:

```
foreach (item item in insert)
```

you can though of course iterate through the `Items` of the `ListBox`:

```
foreach (item item in selected_item.Items)
```

EDIT:

Also your naming pattern is frankly rather confusing. `selected_item` does not sound as if it would represent a collection of things but rather one entity.

Comment: @keshavashourie.b you are welcome. I took the liberty to edit your question, made the title more fitting to the content of your post and removed unnecessary code